# Effect of import order on ByteString type signature

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I'm puzzled by GHCI's behavior around `Data.ByteString` and `Data.ByteString.Char8`. If I load a file with the following imports

```hs
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as E
```

I get

```
*Main> :t E.encodeUtf8
E.encodeUtf8 :: T.Text -> BC.ByteString
```

If I reverse the second and third import lines to

```hs
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as E
```

I get

```
*Main> :t E.encodeUtf8
E.encodeUtf8 :: T.Text -> B.ByteString
```

What that suggests to me is that `Data.ByteString` and `Data.ByteString.Char8` are sharing the same ByteString type, but I don't know how to make sense of that.

Comment: These modules do export the very same `ByteString` type. The difference between these modules is in the functions they expose.

Comment: Ahh, ok. If you'll make this an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: You can test if they are the same type. See if [`Refl :: BC.ByteString :~: B.ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html#t::-126-:) type checks.

Comment: @Iceland_jack, this is pretty far over my head. Any tips on how to use this?

Comment: Haskell has a notion of [type-level equality](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/equality_constraints.html) `(~)` which constrains two types to be equal. For example try running `:set -XTypeFamilies` in ghci and then evaluate `True :: Float ~ Double => Bool`. This will fail to typecheck because `Float` is not equal to `Double`. This equality contraint `(~) :: k -> k -> Constraint` is reified/witnessed by a datatype: `(:~:) :: k -> k -> Type` which is only a wrapper around `(~)`: `data a :~: b where Refl :: (a ~ b) => a :~: b`; the contructor `Refl` witnesses equality.

Comment: The actual type of `Refl :: (a ~ b) => a :~: b` can be simplified to `Refl :: a :~: a` because *a* and *b* are equal. So if you `import Data.Type.Equality` you are able to witness various equalities in the repl (`Refl` stands for "reflexivity"): `Refl :: a :~: a`, `Refl :: String :~: [Char]`, `Refl :: Int :~: Int`. It will compile if the types are equal, and fails for `Refl :: Float :~: Double`. There are low-tech ways of checking equality, elements of lists must have be of the same type (homogeneous) so you could also typecheck `[undefined :: BS.ByteString, undefined :: B.ByteString]`

Comment: Thanks. This will take me some time to digest.

Comment: One use for the equality constraint is [The constraint trick for instances](https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sjakobi's comment answers the question:

> These modules do export the very same `ByteString` type. The
> difference between these modules is in the functions they expose.